# Vue 3: child to parent and parent to child design pattern

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am new to the Vue 3 ecosystem. I am building a search form using the composition API.

I have a child component that contains a search form input. It emits a `doEmitSearch` event, and has a payload of the `searchterm`.

In the parent component I receive the emitted event `@doEmitSearch=”doTriggerSearch”`

In the parent component I have

```
<script lang=”ts” setup>
import {doPerformSearch} from "../composables/doPerformSearch"

function doTriggerSearch (value){
    return doPerformSearch(value)
}
<script/>
```

Inside the `doPerformSearch.ts` I have various functions `Search1(value)`, `Search2(value)`, `Search3(value)` etc. that do API calls for multiple API searches, and data cleaning etc, and each one returns search results as JSON, which I want to dispatch/pass/display in either in the parent component or other child-components as props.

1. What syntax in the composition API can I use to display the returned `doPerformSearch(value)` in the parent component as `{{searchResults}}`
2. What syntax can I use to pass and display multiple search results to child components ?
3. Is that a good design pattern I'm using, or is there better ways to do it ?

Thank you

Comment: please add [vue-component] tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this can help anyone: here is the answer to 1)

```
<script lang=”ts” setup>
import {doPerformSearch} from "../composables/doPerformSearch"

let searchResults = ref(0);

async function doTriggerSearch(value){
  return searchResults.value = await doPerformSearch(value);
}
<script/>
```

and in the template I have `{{searchResults}}`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to start with Vue 3 Docs [Components Basics](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html). Be sure to switch the "API Preference" to Composition API.

[image: Composition API]

I did a very basic concept of your task. Check the code below.

You can make your components statefull, like `searchInput` or stateless, like `searchHistory`. It's up to you, where you store your data in the app.

Important is to understand the data flow with Vue components. Usually, components become data over binding and respond with events.

```js
const { ref, createApp } = Vue;

var searchInput = {     
    emits: ['search'],
    data() {
      return {
        searchValue: ''
      }
    },
    template: `
    <label>Search:</label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" :value="searchValue"
    @input="searchValue = $event.target.value" />&nbsp;
    <button type="button" @click="$emit('search', searchValue)">enter</button>` 
};

var searchHistory = {     
    props: {
        history: {
            type: Array,
            required:true,
            default:[]
        }
    },
    template: `
    <label>Search History:</label>
    <ul><li v-for="item in history">{{item}}</li></ul>`    
};
const app = createApp({
  productionTip: false,
  components: {
    searchInput,
    searchHistory
  },
  data() {
    return {
      searchHistory: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    doSearch(value) {
      if (value != '' && this.searchHistory.indexOf(value) == -1) this.searchHistory.push(value);
    }   
  }
});

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
   <search-input @search="doSearch"></search-input><hr>
   <search-history :history="searchHistory"></search-history>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```